# How can I run "install.com" script in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: software-installation

I have a script file named "install.com" for a software and the instruction reads that I need to execute the .com script file for installation. Now I could not find the proper command to execute the script. Can anybody help me with the command ?

Comment: `chmod u+x install.com` and then `./install.com` should work. It might need sudo privileges. From where have you downloaded the script?

Comment: The file extension `.com` usually hints it's a Windows executable; are you sure the software is for Linux?

Comment: Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how you can improve your question.

Comment: Are you sure that file is a script for linux, not binary file for windows?